# Vue.js component form sends null values

Tags: vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5

the model is Entity. No errors are thrown. The form gets submitted and a new Entity is saved. However, the description and title are both recorded as 'nil'.  to here is `src/components/NewEntity.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="entities">
    <h1>Add Entity</h1>
      <div class="form">
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="TITLE" v-model="title">
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea rows="15" cols="15" placeholder="DESCRIPTION" v-model="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="app_entity_btn" @click="addEntity">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EntitiesService from '@/services/EntitiesService'
export default {
  name: 'NewEntity',
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addEntity () {
      await EntitiesService.addEntity({
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description
      })
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Entities' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

here is where the script imports from (for some reason SO would not initially allow me to include Services/Api.js):

```
services/EntitiesServices:

import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchEntities () {
    return Api().get('/entities')
  },

  addEntity (params) {
    return Api().post('entities', {
      title: params.title,
      description: this.description
    })
  }

services/Api.js:

import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you dump the request in your store method?

Comment: addEntity method (added above) is supposed to post the data. No errors are thrown,  but nothing is passed. both are NULL. And when the record saves, the two values are nil for those attributes. When I view the request in the Network tab of the console, it says "this request has no response data available"

Comment: addEntity posts `this.description` rather than `params.description`.

Comment: I have tried `this` and `params` for both of these. hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OG Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31756756/10599369) by [cperez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5179851/cperez)

Depending on your server, you need to ***'stringify'*** your parameters object within your post function in two possible ways. If your server accepts JSON, then:

```
return Api().post('entities', 
    JSON.stringify({
        title: params.title,
        description: this.description
    })
)
```

If you server doesn't accept JSON, you have to convert the object into encoded URL parameters with the [**querystring** module](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options):

```
var qs = require('querystring');

return Api().post('entities', 
    qs.stringify({
        title: params.title,
        description: this.description
    })
)
```

Comment: The second solution works! **TIL:** my server does not accept json.  Many thanks!