# Jersey POST parameter values always null, but works fine with curl command

Tags: java, node.js, jersey, axios, grizzly

Jersey server code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
public class TestPost {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test(@FormParam("name") final String name) {
        System.out.println("name=" + name);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

We are using Grizzly, if that matters.

This all works great with curl command, like this:

```
>curl -v -d "name=test" http://localhost:7777/test
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7777 (#0)
> POST /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7777
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 2
<
OK* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

and on the server, we see the name parameter successfully logged, thusly:

```
name=test
```

Now... we attempt to do exactly the same trick using Axios:

```
    const data = {
        name,
    };
    axios.post('http://localhost:7777/test', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // 'Content-Length': 9,
            // 'Accept': '*/*',
            // 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.55.1',
            // 'Host': 'localhost:7777',
        }
    }).then((res2, err) => {
        console.log(res2.data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

This request returns "OK"... but now, on the server we see this:

```
name=null
```

I added all the same header values to resemble the curl request, but still the passed parameter is null. Omitting the `Context-Type` header results in a sever error 500, which is also a bit funny.

Note that, using GET rather than POST, everything works fine in both cases.

Comment: try converting data to strinig , like `axios.post('http://localhost:7777/test', JSON.stringify(data), { ....});`

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719674/3461055

Comment: Sure enough!  it is necessary to ´querystring.stringify(data)´ ... for some ungodly reason which is contrary to what axios docs would have us believe. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, it is necessary to ´querystring.stringify(data)´ ... for some unholy reason understood only by the Dark Lord himself. Obviously, this is totally contrary to what the [axios docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) would have us believe:

**DO NOT:**

[image: DON'T DO THIS!]

**DO:**

```
axios.post('/user', querystring.stringify({
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Yeah.  Just.... wow.