# Axios post request body not parsing with mux server

Tags: reactjs, go, axios

I've implemented an API that authenticates users to react clients with Go. The handler for the authentication route is as follows,

```
func (app *application) authenticate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        app.clientError(w, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    username := r.PostForm.Get("username")
    password := r.PostForm.Get("password")

    fmt.Println(r.PostForm)

    u, err := app.user.Get(username, password)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, models.ErrNoRecord) || errors.Is(err, bcrypt.ErrMismatchedHashAndPassword) {
            app.notFound(w)
        } else {
            app.serverError(w, err)
        }
        return
    }

    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

    claims["username"] = u.Username
    claims["name"] = u.Name
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 30).Unix()

    ts, err := token.SignedString(app.secret)
    if err != nil {
        app.serverError(w, err)
        return
    }

    user := models.UserResponse{u.ID, u.Username, u.Name, "Admin", ts}
    js, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        app.serverError(w, err)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
}
```

I'm trying to send a post request to the API from the react app using Axios as follows,

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    username: params.username,
    password: params.password,
});

api.post('/authenticate', data, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    resolve({ ok: true, json: () => response.data });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    reject('Username or password is incorrect');
})
```

But the request returns a 404 error. Go console shows that the post data is empty **map[]** I've tried changing the Content-Type header in the Axios request to **multipart/form-data** and **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** with no luck. When the request is made using CURL,

```
curl -d "username=user&password=password" -X POST http://localhost:4000/authenticate
```

The request returns the proper response. Postman is also working fine. What could be the possible issue that the request body is not parsed in Go when only the request is made from Axios?

Answer (score 1):

Working solution is using the package **qs** to stringify data.

```
import qs from 'qs';

const data = {
    username: params.username,
    password: params.password,
};

api.post('/authenticate', qs.stringify(data)
).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    resolve({ ok: true, json: () => response.data });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    reject('Username or password is incorrect');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FormData.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.set('username', params.username);
data.set('password', params.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your client request, you are sending a JSON body; however on the server you're expecting url-encoded values.

You should either change your client to send the correct data, e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719674), or you need to accept the JSON body by parsing it with the [`encoding/json`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) package on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about Stringifying when using `axios`. The library does it automatically by default. You should go for something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/api' 
})
async signIn(username, password) {
   try {
      const resp = await api.post('/authenticate', data);
      return resp.data
   } catch(error) {
      throw new Error(error?.message || "something went wrong")
   }
}
```

you can then call it in a React component.

```
signIn(username, password)
   .then(data => setState(data))
   .catch(err => alert(error.message)
```