# Javascript: fetch and post array in object with x-www-form

Tags: javascript, fetch, x-www-form-urlencoded

This is my object:

```
        data: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            color: '',
            extra: [{'full':'1'}, {'full':'2'}]
        }
```

id, name and color post fine, but extra post as [object][object]

I use `data.extra = JSON.stringify(data.extra)` but not work

My code:

```
fetch('/save/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Token': Tools.userToken(),
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams(data)
        })
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `URLSearchParams` in a `POST` method. Have you checked by directly passing the `data` in `body`?

Comment: @parkourkarthik i use x-www-form, for this reason I most use URLSearchParams. otherwise I use json. I dont want use json

Comment: May be the answers in this thread could help..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756756/axios-http-client-how-to-construct-http-post-url-with-form-params